# Cordova 7.x creating dir error

Tags: javascript, cordova, filesystems

When building my app I've encountered the couldn't find Android SDK error. Updating Cordova from 4.x to 7.x did the trick of fixing this issue. However, now my app doesn't write directories anymore (in this case 1 directory in the root folder). The fileSystem.root.getDirectory() returns error code 12 (PATH_EXISTS_ERR). Since it's an directory in the root, it should work right?

Anybody an idea how this issue can be solved?

My code:

```
function writeFile(file, data, functionName) {
    console.log('writeFile');
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
        console.log('requestFileSystem');
        console.log(config.folder);
        fileSystem.root.getDirectory(config.folder, {create: true}, function(dirEntry){
            console.log('getDirectory');
            dirEntry.getFile(file, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function(fileEntry){
                console.log('getFile');
                fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter){
                    console.log('writing...');
                    fileWriter.write(data);
                    if(functionName != '') {
                        console.log('writed');
                        window[functionName](true);
                    }
                    console.log('end writing');
                }, function(writeError){
                    console.log(writeError);
                });
            }, function(fileError){
                console.log(fileError);
            });
        }, function(dirError){
            console.log(dirError)
        });
    }, function(fileSystemError){
        console.log(fileSystemError)
    }); 
    console.log('end writeFile');
}
```

Comment: Are you testing on android 6+? Looks like you don't have runtime permission. You should add a runtime permission plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Totally forgot about the runtime permissions since Android 6.0. Added a runtime permission plugin to make it work again.